# Passing params to path from another controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This code just works fine, but I'm sure rails has a better way to achieve the same result.

```
<%= link_to (image_tag post.image1(:thumb)), (posts_path+"/"+(post.id).to_s) %>
```

Comment: Can you specify your question a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work too:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag post.image1(:thumb)), post %>
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes I miss the simplest things!